# Kivy TextInput text spacing issues

Tags: kivy

Does anybody have an idea why printed text shows properly in command prompts/terminals but Kivy's TextInput seems to distort it, there's an issue wit spaces.

```
Will show properly in Command Prompts/Terminals with print() like
###################
#      This       #
###################

But...

Will show like this in TextInput widget.
##################
#     This  #      
##################
```

Anyways to preserve the formating?

Comment: Try setting the `font` of the `TextInput` to a monospace font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text may look different in the TextInput widget than the terminal because the two use different fonts. The terminal (by default) uses a monospace font, meaning all characters take up the same space. Kivy (by default) does not use a monospace font so the different characters take up a different amount of space, causing text like what you provided to look misaligned.

To make the text in the TextInput monospace, you can change its `font_name` to a monospace font.

If you need to, you can use any monospace font you want in your app by registering it with LabelBase from `kivy.core.text`. Somewhere in your python file put `LabelBase.register('font name', fn_regular='path to the font')` after importing LabelBase.